# mongodb ops manager configuration

Tags: mongodb

I have installed ops manager version 1.6. The Ops Manager Application databases and the Backup Blockstore databases belong to the same mongodb instance.

I would like to separate Application databases and Blockstore databases each on it's own mongodb instance. In conf-deamon.properties it is mentionned:

```
# The following connection string MUST match the configuration
# in the conf-mms.properties file from the mongodb-mms package.
# MMS database server(s)
mongo.mongoUri=
```

Can we separate these two services?